# Python Resources

Tags: python, resources

Is there anyway to incorporate a "resources" folder with .exe's inside of it, with my python program?? I basically want to bundle .exe's with my .py file... My python program depends on these executables... If this isn't possible, would it be possible to convert .exe to .py???

Comment: How do you package and deplay? With distutils?

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, yes. Just put it in a known subdirectory and manipulate `__file__` with `os.path` to get the path to pass to `subprocess`.

For the second... no. Just no.

Comment: okay. So, I should be able to convert my final python program into a single .exe using something like py2exe?? right now, I just have python browse for the exe in the folder. I want to compile the folder, along with the .py into one single .exe Would this be possible?

Comment: You will probably be unable to safely package the resources in your .exe, and I don't know how you would refer to the location of your .exe.